# `let` inside `let` in Kotlin: how to access the first `it`

Tags: kotlin

I have one `let` inside another one

```
    someMethodCall()?.let{
        // ....
        // some code here
        // ....
        val resultCall = it
        someMethod2Call()?.let {
            // ...
            val myVariable = it + resultCall
            // ... 
        }
    }
```

Is it possible in Kotlin inside the second `let` get access to `it` of first `let` and avoid using `resultCall` variable?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`it` is a default name for the lambda argument. `it` is convenient for short lambdas, but you should not use it for longer lambdas. For longer lambdas make the code more readable by specifying an explicit argument name:

```
someMethodCall()?.let {
    resultCall ->
    // ... some code that uses "resultCall" instead of "it" ...
}
```

Use different names to avoid shadowing of the variable in the inner block as in your example:

```
someMethodCall()?.let {
    resultCall ->
    // ... some code here ...
    someMethod2Call()?.let {
        resultCall2 ->
        // ...
        val myVariable = resultCall2 + resultCall
        // ... 
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

No it's not possible and you should definitely use explicit names for the parameters in such use cases:

```
someMethodCall()?.let{ v1->
    // ....
    // some code here
    // ....

    someMethod2Call()?.let { v2->

    }
}
```

Comment: Also see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#lambda-parameters

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you name your variables.

```
someMethodCall()?.let { resultCall ->
    // ....
    // some code here
    // ....
    someMethod2Call()?.let { otherResult ->
        // ...
        val myVariable = resultCall + otherResult
        // ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way

```
  someMethodCall()?.let{ nameOne ->
       // ....
       // some code here
       // ....
       val resultCall = nameOne
       someMethod2Call()?.let { -> nameTwo
          // ...
          val myVariable = nameTwo + resultCall
          // ... 
      }
 }
```